# how to set Firefox 94 cache location on ubuntu 20.04.3

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, command-line-interface, nfs, ubuntu-20.04

background:
firefox 94 on ubuntu 20.04.3 machines using autofs to mount remote homedirs

problem:
Firefox takes a very long time to load, when launched from a user account with a network-mounted homedir. When launched from a local account on the same machine, firefox loads instantaneously.

suspected problem (and fix?):
I suspect the cache is slowing things down, and I would like to run a terminal command to relocate the cache to a non-network-mounted directory.

Any assistance you might provide will be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Ah-ha!

This site was very helpful:

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Locking_preferences

It was as simple as adding a lock-preferences file to the firefox install dir, then telling firefox to load said file...

```
sudo nano /usr/lib/firefox/mozilla.cfg
```

...and enter

```
//
lockPref("browser.cache.disk.parent_directory", "/tmp/");
```

...then add the script to tell firefox where to load these settings:

```
sudo nano /usr/lib/firefox/defaults/pref/local-settings.js
```

```
pref("general.config.obscure_value", 0); // only needed if you do not want to obscure the content with ROT-13
pref("general.config.filename", "mozilla.cfg");
```